# django-private-chat /dialogs is empty

Tags: python, django, chat

I followed the steps in guide in https://django-private-chat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html:

base.html:

```
{% block extra_js %}{% endblock extra_js %}
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_private_chat',
    ...
)

CHAT_WS_SERVER_HOST = 'localhost'
CHAT_WS_SERVER_PORT = 5002
CHAT_WS_SERVER_PROTOCOL = 'ws'


urlpatterns = [
    "other urls"
    url(r'^', include('django_private_chat.urls')),
]
```

After starting the server I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/dialogs/some-of-the-users and there is no result whatsoever, the page is empty.

The console displaying:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at username:128
```

django version= 3.0.6 
python version= 3.7.6
and the latest version of django-private-messaging

It's my first time implementing a chat app so I hope I'm not missing anything fundamental. Have a nice day!

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="tr">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/dropdown.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/intro.css' %}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="{% static 'icons\favicon.ico' %}"/>


    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="overlay2" id="overlay2">
        <div id=fullscrean>
            <img class=virus2 src="{% static 'icons\virus-new-color.png' %}" alt="virus">
            <h4></h3>
            <a href="/user/loginUser" class=mantar>login</a>
            <a href="/user/register" class=mantar>register</a>
            <button class=button-geri onclick="close('overlay2') ">geri</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
        <div id=fullscrean>
            <img class=virus2 src="{% static 'icons\virus-new-color.png' %}" alt="virus">
            <h4></h3>
            <a href="/user/loginUser" class=mantar>enter</a>
            <a href="/user/register" class=mantar>register</a>
            <button class=button-geri onclick="kapat('overlay') ">back</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay4" id="overlay4">
        <div id=fullscrean>
            <img class=virus2 src="{% static 'icons\virus-new-color.png' %}" alt="virus">
            <h4></h3>
            <a href="/user/loginUser" class=mantar></a>
            <a href="/user/register" class=mantar></a>
            <button class=button-geri onclick="kapat('overlay4') "></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay5" id="overlay5">
        <div id=fullscrean>
            <img class=virus2 src="{% static 'icons\virus-new-color.png' %}" alt="virus">
            <h3></h3>
            <a href="/user/loginUser" class=mantar></a>
            <a href="/user/register" class=mantar></a>
            <button class=button-geri onclick="kapat('overlay5') "></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay3" id="overlay3">
        <div id=fullscrean2>
            <img class=virus3 src="{% static 'icons\delete.png' %}"
                    alt="sil"></button>
            <h4></h3>
            <button class=button-cancel onclick="kapat('overlay3')">vazgeç</button>
            <button class=button-doit id=doit>sil</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay6" id="overlay6">
        <div id=fullscrean3>
            <div class=scrollable-div id=scrollable-div>
                {% for i in page_list %}
                    {% if i == entries2.number %}
                    <a class=scroll-select id=exception2 href="?page={{i}}"><span id=exception>{{i}}</span></a>
                    {% else %}
                    <a class=scroll-select href="?page={{i}}">{{i}}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            {% if entries2.has_previous or entries.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ entries2.previous_page_number }}"><button class=button-prevp>önceki</button></a>
            {% endif %}
            {% if entries2.has_next or entries.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ entries2.next_page_number }}"><button class=button-nextp>sonraki</button></a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay7" id="overlay7">
        <div id=fullscrean2>
            <img class=virus3 src="{% static 'icons\delete.png' %}"
                    alt="sil"></button>
            <h4>etiketin silinsin mi?</h3>
            <button class=button-cancel onclick="kapat('overlay7')">vazgeç</button>
            <button class=button-doit id=doit2>sil</button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class=line></div>
    <header>
        <div class="header-top">
            <div class=logo-holder>
                <img class=virus src="{% static 'icons\virus-new-color.png' %}" alt="virus">
            </div>
            <div class=search-holder>
                <input class=search type="text" placeholder="search it..." />
                <button type="submit" class=search-button><img src="{% static 'icons\icons8_search.png' %}"
                        alt="search"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <div class=mobile-only>
                <ul class=navul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/today"><b></b></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="debe"><b></b></a>
                    </li>
                    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="/user/{{request.user.first_name}}--{{request.user.id}}"><b></b></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'user:logout' %}"><b></b></a>
                    </li>
                    {% else %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'user:login' %}"><b></b></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'user:register' %}"><b></b></a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class=line2></div>
    <main id=main>
        {% if messages %}
        <ul class="messages">
            {% for message in messages %}
            <li {% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}" {% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
        {% block extra_js %}{% endblock extra_js %}

        {% block body %}

        {% endblock body %}
    </main>
</body>

<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.mini.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/dropdown.js' %}"></script>
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        var message_ele = document.getElementsByClassName("messages")[0];  
            message_ele.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
            message_ele.style.opacity = 0;
            message_ele.style.transition= "visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear";
        }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function(){ 
        var message_ele = document.getElementsByClassName("errorlist")[0];  
            message_ele.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
            message_ele.style.opacity = 0;
            message_ele.style.transition= "visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear";
        }, 2000);

    function kapat(id){
        var geri=document.getElementById(id);
        geri.style.display="none";
        $('body').css('overflow', 'scroll');
    }

    $("#overlay6").click(function (e) {
        if(e.target !== e.currentTarget) return;
        $("#overlay6").css("display","none")
        $('body').css('overflow', 'scroll');
   });

   $("#overlay3").click(function (e) {
    if(e.target !== e.currentTarget) return;
    $("#overlay3").css("display","none")
    $('body').css('overflow', 'scroll');
});

    $("#overlay7").click(function (e) {
        if(e.target !== e.currentTarget) return;
        $("#overlay7").css("display","none")
        $('body').css('overflow', 'scroll');
    });



</script>


{% block javascript %}{% endblock %} 

</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you install jQuery?

Comment: I have it installed already

Comment: but your `extra_js` is empty?

Comment: I think it's in in dialogs.html template of the django-private-chat app. Edit:, yeap it's there.

Comment: I doubt that, can you check the page source code, and see if it imported?

Comment: It is imported indeed. "  var base_ws_server_path = "ws://localhost:5002/";
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var websocket = null;
            var monitor = null;
" this part is highlighed as the source of the error.

Comment: but does it contain a `<script src="path/to/jquery.js">` if not, then your code *uses* jQuery, but you did not import it, hence the JS interpreter does not understand `$`.

Comment: Let me add my base.html here, it might be misplaced.